# Microsoft Active Directory On-Demand Assessment not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory

I configured Microsoft on demand assessment for Active Directory:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/unified/health/getting-started-ad

It seems all good but there are no results on the Log Analytics on Azure.
I use the new Azure Monitor Agent installed on a server on premises, not the legacy MMA.

The scheduled task seems working well, the ARC Agent is correctly connected to Azure, I can't see any error on the collection server, but nothing is uploaded on Azure.

Do someone know why and how to solve it?

I followed the troubleshooting guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/unified/health/assessments-troubleshooting